# Double inner join with grouping

Tags: sql

Here's one for the SQL junkies:

I have two tables: student names and student registrations. A student will register 1 or 2 times in a year, and over the course of a degree 8 to 10 times. I want to pull up all the students currently in the system (i.e. all students in 2013), which I do with the following:

```
SELECT studentkey, lastname, firstname, COUNT(year) AS registrations
    FROM  uctProgrammesRegistered 
    LEFT JOIN uctStudents
    ON uctStudents.studentnumber=uctProgrammesRegistered.studentkey
    WHERE programmeregistered='".$programmeCode."' AND year='".$year."' 
    GROUP BY studentkey, lastname, firstname
    ORDER BY studentkey, lastname
```

This gives me the result with the number of times registered in the current year. However, what I really want is the number of times ever registered by the students over all previous years registered. Note this can't be solved by just relaxing the year=$year part of the WHERE since that will give me all students ever registered in the institution. I just want from the students presently registered to know how many times this group of students registered.

I thought using the JOIN statement multiple times should help (i.e. include another join on the same table uctProgrammesRegistered, but somehow with only WHERE programmeregistered='".$programmeCode."' and leaving off the year check - that would work, but SQL doesn't seem to cooperate with this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Select studentkey, lastname, firstname, 
     Count(*) registrations
From  uctStudents s
   Join uctProgrammesRegistered  r 
       on r.studentkey = s.studentnumber
Where Exists(Select * from uctProgrammesRegistered 
             Where studentkey = s.studentnumber
                 And year='".$year."')
Group By studentkey, lastname, firstname
Order By studentkey, lastname
```

or ...

```
Select studentkey, lastname, firstname, 
     Sum(Case when year = 2013 then 1 else 0 end) Registrations2013,
     Count(*) TotalRegistrations
From  uctStudents s
   Join uctProgrammesRegistered  r 
       on r.studentkey = s.studentnumber
Where Exists(Select * from uctProgrammesRegistered 
             Where studentkey = s.studentnumber
                 And year='".$year."')
Group By studentkey, lastname, firstname
Order By studentkey, lastname
```